# How can I turn a Img src into a string place it into an array and encode with json?

Tags: php, javascript, sql

Hi I'm using the function json_encode to retrieve data from a database via an associative array. However I wanted to ask how can I turn the img tag into a string and place it into the associative array then have json encode it and spit back out all while maintaining that img tag as a string?

```
 while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
  $id= (float)$row['id'];
  $name = $row['name'];
  $color1 = $row['color'];
  $type1 = $row['type'];
  $to= (float)$row['to']; 
  $thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path

  $array = array(
  "adjacencies" => array( array(
  "nodeTo" => "$to",
  "nodeFrom" => "$id",
  "data" => array() )),
  "data" => array(
   "$"."color" => $color1,
   "$"."type" => $type1 ),
  "id" => $id,
  "name" => "<img src='$thumb' height='30' width='30' alt='root'/><label>$name</label> ");
}
$json = json_encode($array);
print "$json";
return $json;
```

Comment: what you're doing doesn't work?

Comment: no the browser returns null as the value in the Name key pair

Comment: Looking at your code, this should work? Also, why cast $row['id'] as a float? Also, you are overwriting your $array value each time you loop.

Comment: json encoding picks up my int as a sting so I have to manually cast it.

Comment: should I put that $array into an array? like $array =Array[], $array= array(iteration);

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array=array();
while($row=$result->FetchRow())
{
    $id= (float)$row['id'];
    $name = $row['name'];
    $color1 = $row['color'];
    $type1 = $row['type'];
    $to= (float)$row['to']; 
    $thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path

    $array = array(
        "adjacencies" => array( array(
            "nodeTo" => "$to",
            "nodeFrom" => "$id",
            "data" => array() 
        )),
        "data" => array(
            "$"."color" => $color1,
            "$"."type" => $type1 ),
        "id" => $id,
        "name" =>htmlspecialchars("<img src='".$thumb."' height='30' width='30' alt='root'/><label>".$name."</label>")
    );
}
$json = json_encode($array);
echo $json;
return $json;
```

Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: {"adjacencies":[{"nodeTo":"2","nodeFrom":"1","data":[]}],"data":{"$color":"#83548B","$type":"circle"},"id":1,"name":"<img src='soccer' height='30' width='30' alt='root'\/><label>Blue Jay<\/label>"}

Answer (score 0):

First thing, you are overwriting $array each time you pass your loop. Consider fixing the following lines

```
...
$thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path

$array = array(
"adjacencies" => array( array(
"nodeTo" => "$to",
...
```

To

```
...
$thumb =$row['thumb']; //image path

$array[] = array(
"adjacencies" => array( array(
"nodeTo" => "$to",
...
```

Other than that, just tried out your code with some default variables

```
$id = $to = 1;
$color1 = 'green';
$type1 = 'type1';
$thumb = 'image.jpg';
$name = 'image name';
$array = array(
    "adjacencies" => array(
        array(
            "nodeTo" => $to,
            "nodeFrom" => $id,
            "data" => array()
        )
    ),
    "data" => array(
        "$"."color" => $color1,
        "$"."type" => $type1
    ),
    "id" => $id,
    "name" => "<img src='$thumb' height='30' width='30' alt='root'/><label>$name</label> "
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Returns me this JSON, which seems to be what you are looking for?

```
{
    "adjacencies": [
        {
            "nodeTo": 1,
            "nodeFrom": 1,
            "data": []
        }
    ],
    "data": {
        "$color": "green",
        "$type": "type1"
    },
    "id": 1,
    "name": "<img src='image.jpg' height='30' width='30' alt='root'/><label>image name</label> "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use htmlspecialchars to make sure any problematic characters are escaped (http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php). Other than that, it is just string data until you insert it into the DOM.

I am assuming that with each iteration of your loop, you are intending to add another element to your array, $array. You want to initialize the $array variable before the loop

```
$array = array()
```

and instead of

```
$array = array(
...
)
```

in the loop, do

```
$array[$key] = array(
...
)
```

where $key is the key you want to use to index the array. I'm assuming you want to use $id for this. You could also increment an integer and use that.